# cannot understand nested ternary operator

Tags: c, ternary-operator

```
int main(void)
{
  int i = 10, j =20;
  j = i, j ?  (i, j) ? i : j : j;
  printf("%d %d", i, j);
  return 0;
}
```

What is the output?

Please somebody guide me how to interpret the nested ternary operator in this case.

Comment: Use an operator precedence table (e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) to figure this out.

Comment: If you keep doing weird things, everyone will hate you.

Comment: -3?! Using such an operator is bad, but not asking about it. I'd be confused as well.

Comment: Please avoid interview questions. its not for SO!!

Comment: @glglgl: The thing is, if this code *only* consisted of nested ternary operators, it would be simple (there's only one conceivable way to interpret `a ? b ? c : d : e`).  The problem is the introduction of the comma operator.  The end result is some nonsensical code.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth You and I can read it with a glance. Others maybe not. That doesn't make it a bad question. YMMV.

Comment: @glglgl: I can't read it at a glance, I can't remember the precedence order off-hand ;)  My complaint is more that typing some random code and then posting it on SO is not particularly constructive...

Comment: @VinayakPingale if that is an interview question, then you know you dont want the job...

Answer (score 3):

What you have here is hopefully code you have read and you want to get rid of, not code you actually use.

You have a combination of two unparenthesed ternay operators and two uses of the comma operator.

Despite no use of parentheses, the nesting of `?:` is unambiguous:

```
a ? b ? c : d : e
```

can only mean

```
a ? ( b ? c : d) : e
```

as there is no other way to interpret it.

The 2nd comma operator is in parentheses, so it is unambiguous as well.

The only point of doubt is the comma operator at the start, where you might want to consult a precedence table.

Here we see that `,` has the lowest precedence and thus we have

```
(j = i), (j ?  (i, j) ? i : j : j);
```

which is a comma operator with an assignment as first expression and an unevaluated other expression as second expression, which is the result.

In short, if we omit the right side, which isn't used nevertheless, we just have `j = i`, but this expression lacks unreadability.

So the output is `10 10`.

Great trap, this expression... but as it is written, the answer doesn't cover this. If I erroneously evaluated it as `j = j ? i : j;` I would get `10 10` as well.

Answer (score 3):

C is defined by a language grammar;  a precedence table is a handy condensing of the grammar into something that humans can take in at a glance,  but it doesn't exactly correspond to what the grammar specifies.

You may need to consult the language grammar in order to resolve associativity around a ternary operator. Personally I always explicitly use parentheses so that a reader who's not a language lawyer can still understand what's going on (and so that I don't make mistakes).

An example is:

```
c ? c = a : c = b
```

which must be parsed as

```
(c ? c = a : c) = b
```

which is illegal in C, since the ternary operator does not give an lvalue.  Incidentally, the C++ grammar is different; in that language this is parsed as

```
c ? c = a : (c = b)
```

which is legal; and also the ternary operator can give an lvalue in C++.

In your case, the question is which of the following it is:

```
Z = ((i , j) ? X : Y)
Z = (i , (j ? X : Y))
(Z = i, j) ? X : Y
(Z = i), (j ? X : Y)
```

I believe the latter is correct here, so you should end up with `j = i` plus an expression with no side-effect.

Comment: Just wanted to say that while your suggestededit to [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297564/difference-between-extern-and-volatile/21297642#21297642) was unfortunately rejected, you were absolutely correct. So I made the edit and attributed it to you. Thanks!